# Unit Testing Passport Strategy / NestJS Guard

Tags: unit-testing, nestjs, passport.js

I have a JWTGuard() decorator which follows the implementation as described in https://docs.nestjs.com/security/authentication#jwt-functionality

It looks like so:

```js
import { ExecutionContext, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Reflector } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { IS_PUBLIC_ROUTE } from '../decorators/public-route.decorator';

@Injectable()
export class JWTAuthenticationGuard extends AuthGuard('jwt') {
  constructor(private readonly reflector: Reflector) {
    super();
  }
 canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): Promise<boolean> {
    const isPublic = this.reflector.getAllAndOverride<boolean>(
      IS_PUBLIC_ROUTE,
      [context.getHandler(), context.getClass()],
    );

    if (isPublic) return true;

    return super.canActivate(context)
  }
}
```

It works as expected, but having difficulty unit testing the guard. In short, I want to test three things:

- If IS_PUBLIC_ROUTE is set, then canActivate() returns true ✅ this unit test works
- If an expired/invalid/incorrectly signed token is passed, canActivate() returns false ❌
- If a valid token is found, canActivate() returns true ❌

I tried to follow https://github.com/jmcdo29/testing-nestjs/blob/master/apps/complex-sample/src/cat/cat.guard.spec.ts which just tests a bare guard, not extending a Passport Guard.

Tests are setup as follows:

```js
  let guard: JWTAuthenticationGuard;
  const reflector = new Reflector();

  beforeEach(() => {
    guard = new JWTAuthenticationGuard(reflector);
    passport.use('jwt', new JWTStrategy());
  });
```

The first test (should return false)

```js
 it('should return false if no authorization token is found', () => {
    const context = createMock<ExecutionContext>();

    const result = guard.canActivate(context);

    expect(result).toBe(false);
  });
```

My test never even makes it to the `expect()` clause, as it has thrown an UnauthorisedException and the test suite exits entirely.

I tried debugging inside the canActivate() method, and checking the type of super.canActivate() which tells me that it's a pending promise. I tried awaiting it, but still says its Pending, I tried wrapping in a try/catch, but the catch block never runs. Reading through the code of passport's AuthGuard, it never throws either.

I tried to add a valid token:

```js
it('should return false if no authorization token is found', async () => {
    const context = createMock<ExecutionContext>();
    expect(context.switchToHttp()).toBeDefined();
    context.switchToHttp().getRequest.mockReturnValue({
      headers: {
        Authorization:
          'Bearer ey...[truncated]...dE',
      },
    });

    const result = await guard.canActivate(context);

    expect(result).toBe(true);
```

however I still just get an UnauthorisedException thrown from god knows where at the `result = guard.can...` line, and still never makes it to the expect.

Any guidance would be appriciated.